# Devise - Timeout not working

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Devise does not time out a user in the following scenario:

A user logs in, closes the tab, and then re-visits the URL in timeout + X minutes. The user is still logged in.

Timeouts work properly if the tab is already open, and is refreshed/clicked later. Which means the `timeoutable` module is working properly for this scenario.

Also so far, I've only been able to reproduce this in non localhost environments.

[This question has also been asked before](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plataformatec-devise/qJUeh0T79t8) on the Devise groups, with no answer.

Versions:

Devise 2.2.4

Rails 3.2.13

Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: I was the one who posted on Google Groups and I never did find a solution - we decided it wasn't a high priority so the issue was left at the bottom of the pile. I'm looking at it again today though so I'll report back if I find anything!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix this by uncommenting `config.timeout_in = 30.minutes` in `devise.yml`. It says that the default is 30 minutes but it was only by explicitly setting the timeout to 30 minutes in the config that I could make it work if the window/tab was closed.